# Choose which android device (emulator or phone) will react-native run-android run on

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing a `react-native` application and every time I want to update the changes to either an actual phone or an emulator, I execute `react-native run-android` (Sometimes I use the reload functionality in the emulator).

My question is whether there is the possibility to specify in which device/emulator the command will run, since when I have both connected it will run and update the app in the most recently run/plugged.

So I would imagine something like this:

```
react-native run-android --device=XXXXXX
```

I have been doing some research and haven't found an answer so far, so I hope someone has a clue about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### If you have just one device, either plugged in or running as emulator:

```
npx react-native run-android // or if you have a npm script, 'npm run android'
```

### The following is useful if you have multiple devices, either plugged in or running as emulators.

Ensure the devices are plugged in, and get their deviceIds with `adb devices`, then `npx react-native run-android --deviceId [DEVICE_ID]`

First, plug the device in, or start the emulator with [Android Emulator CLI](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline).

1. `emulator -list-avds` will list your avds (android virtual devices), e.g. `Pixel_2_API_29`
2. `emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29` or `emulator @Pixel_2_API_29` will start a specified device.
3. `emulator -help` for more info.
4. Then, open a new terminal/ tab, run either `npx react-native run-android`. **It will start your app on all android devices, both physical and AVDs.**
   **If you wanted to specify only 1 device** (why not run on all of them!):
5. `adb devices`, to get list of device IDs, e.g. `1cfe4i231414523`
6. `npx react-native run-android --deviceId 1cfe4i231414523`

PS: React native getting started guide specifies that you should uninstall react-native, and instead use the package through npx. To uninstall `npm rm -g react-native`. Now, everytime you want to run react-native, use `npx react-native [command]`. What npx does is it looks in the local `node_modules` and runs it from there, as opposed to a possibly outdated global `react-native` package.

Answer (score 1):

If you go through the docs then you would find that there are two more commands available to start the server and there is no such react-native run-android ---//deviceID command available until now but, you can customize react native code in node_modules to make that command for yourself.

The two commands are:

```
1)react-native start
2)npm start
```

Cheers :)